# Given a 4 digit number, (3,300) add the numbers between the range (1-300) that are multiples of the first digit (3)

Tags: java

Given any 4 digit number (3,300 for example), write a program that adds the numbers to the right of the comma (ex: 1-300) that are multiples of the first digit (3).

So far, i only know how to add all of the digits of a number, not a certain range.

```
enter code here 
                 public class add {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int w = 4400;
    int last = w;
    System.out.print(last(w));
    for (int i=0; i<=400; i++){
    if (i%4 == 0){
    System.out.print(i);
    }
    else {
    System.out.println();
    w = w + i;
    return;
    }

    }
    }

    public static int last (int w){
    return (Math.abs(w%11));

    }
    }
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: How can i separate this range to the right of the comma and add its numbers that are multiples of the first digit

Comment: it seems to be **can you do my homework for me?**

Comment: I failed this question on an exam and i would just like to see the solution to make more sense of it

Comment: then you need to edit the question, post the attempted solutions code and what is wrong with it and tell what you don't understand specifically; make this a real question or go toss it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com, this isn't a question as it stands now

Comment: How on EARTH is this a duplicate of that other question?  I agree that it's a very bad question; but it's absolutely not a duplicate of that one, and should not have been closed as such.

Comment: the duplicate question didn't really clear anything up for me

Comment: I can't figure out how to print the sum of the printed numbers. here is what I have:
public class add {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  int w = 4400;
  int last = w;
  System.out.print(last(w));
  for (int i=0; i<=400; i++){
  if (i%4 == 0){
  System.out.print(i);
  }
  else {
  System.out.println();
  w = w + i;
  return;
  }
   
  }
  }
   
  public static int last (int w){
  return (Math.abs(w%11));
  
  }
  }

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here           
                 public class add {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int sum = 0;
    int w = 4400;
    int last = w;
    System.out.print(last(w));
    for (int i=0; i<=400; i++){
    if (i%4 == 0){
    System.out.print(i);
    }
    else {
    System.out.println();
    sum = sum + i;


    }

    }
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
    }

    public static int last (int w){
    return (Math.abs(w%11));

    }

    }
```